# Retrieving HTML from a URL on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, https, python-requests

I use Heroku to host my telegram bot.
The purpose of the bot is to retrieve html from a webpage and convert it to pdf.

After successfully hosting it online, i tried sending an URL to the bot, but it freezes/stops at the moment of sending a get request.

Code:

```
logger.info('retrieving HTML = {}'.format(url))
page_html = requests.get(url)

logger.info('retrieved HTML')
logger.info('started HTML parsing')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html.text, 'html.parser')
```

In the Heroku logs i only see `retrieving HTML = <URL>` and than the application does not show any sign of activity.

I tried to connect to the dyno (the app itself on heroku) using the heroku console (accessible from the heroku web page), and entered the following code:

```
import requests
# url of a recepie
url = 'https://pikabu.ru/story/pirog_quotlen__matushkaquot_5332461'
html = requests.get(url)
```

the execution of this code in the heroku console takes very long time as well and does not finish (no error, no message, i can stop the process with crtl+c, execution never finishes), and i am not sure what could be the problem.

Thank You in advance, any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to load this page :https://pikabu.ru/story/pirog_quotlen__matushkaquot_5332461

Comment: @bhansa yes, i can open it. Just add `https://` in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing info from your logs, or getting a sense of how big the page you want to scrape is, my guess is that you are hitting Heroku's 30 second timeout.

From [the Dev Center article on timeouts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout):

> The request must then be processed in the dyno by your application,
>   and a response delivered back to the router, within 30 seconds to
>   avoid the timeout.

I would check your logs (`heroku logs -t -a yourAppName`) while running the script and look for `h12` which is the timeout error code. Or if you are using hobby or above dynos, you could check [application metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/metrics) on the Dashboard.